# YII Call to a member function getErrors() on a non-objec

Tags: yii, updatemodel

Following [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/) tutorial; When I try to get the data to display in the form and update

For my error was:

```
$n = $this->loadModel($id);
```

I want to make two models with one form, this is my code for update:

Controller:

```
    public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $n = new Noticias;
    $m = new Multimedia;

    $this->performAjaxValidation(array($n,$m));
    $n=$this->loadModel($id);


    if(isset($_POST['Noticias'],$_POST['Multimedia']))
    {
        $n->attributes=$_POST['Noticias'];
        $m->attributes=$_POST['Multimedia'];

        $m->ID_NOT=$n->ID;
        $m->setIsNewRecord(false);

        if($n->save())
            $this->redirect(array('admin','id'=>$n->ID));
    }

    $this->render('update',array('n'=>$n,'m'=>$m));
}
```

update.php

```
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('n'=>$n, 'm'=>$m)); ?>
```

some view

```
//get Multimedia FK
<?php if ($n->isNewRecord==false) { 
    $m=Multimedia::model()->findByPk($n->ID);
} ?>

//Validation
<?php echo $form->errorSummary(array($n,$m)); ?>

//Field FOTO between other
<div class="row">
   <?php echo $form->labelEx($m,'FOTO_URL'); ?>
   <?php echo $form->textField($m,'FOTO_URL',array('size'=>25,'maxlength'=>100)); ?>
   <?php echo $form->error($m,'FOTO'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: that mean you are not get any data... check again when you get data

Comment: Feel free to explain, where did you get the errors form which parts ?

Comment: A little more specific would definitely be a help. Are you trying to load model individually?

Answer (score 0):

First - do not load models in view

```
<?php if ($n->isNewRecord==false) { 
    $m=Multimedia::model()->findByPk($n->ID);
} ?>
```

This part should be in controller action.
Make sure `$m` and `$n` are really models. If `findByPk` statement above fails, `$m` will be `null`, so you will get error from `errorSummary` which calls `$m->getErrors()` and `$n->getErrors()`. In short - make sure `$n` **and** `$m` are properly initialized - both must be instances of model, either empty, or filled from db, but in your case one is `null`. Most probably `$m`

Comment: but intance $n = new Noticias; $m = new Multimedia; -- I think it is also empty but as full

Comment: But in your view `$m` might be set to null. Try `var_dump` this in your view just before `//Validation`

Answer (score 0):

this error occur when Noticias (ie $n is newrecord) or `$n->ID` is not found in Multimedia
you can solve this if you need to work even if its a new record you can use.

```
if ($n->isNewRecord==false) {
    $m=Multimedia::model()->findByPk($n->ID);
}    
else
 $m=new Multimedia;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load both models in Controller (ex. in actionUpdate) :

```
public function actionUpdate($id) 
{
   $n = new Noticias;
   $m = new Multimedia;

   $this->performAjaxValidation(array($n,$m));
   $n=$this->loadModelNoticias($id);
   $m=$this->loadModelMultimedia($n->ID);  //just put it here..


   if(isset($_POST['Noticias'],$_POST['Multimedia']))
   {
      $n->attributes=$_POST['Noticias'];
      $m->attributes=$_POST['Multimedia'];

      $m->ID_NOT=$n->ID;
      $m->setIsNewRecord(false);

      if($n->save())
          $this->redirect(array('admin','id'=>$n->ID));
   }

   $this->render('update',array('n'=>$n,'m'=>$m));
}
```

Please be noticed that you have to define both loadModel functions in the same controller too.

```
function loadModelNoticias($id){
   $model = Noticias::model()->findByPk($id);
   return $model;
}

function loadModelMultimedia($id){
   $model = Multimedia::model()->findByPk($id);
   return $model;
}
```